# make_shared returns error C2665: no overloaded function could convert all the argument types

Tags: c++, shared-ptr, make-shared

A sample question on c++ primer: Add member named `get_file` that returns a `shared_ptr` to the file in the `QueryResult` object.

```
class QueryResult
{
    friend std::ostream& print(std::ostream&, const QueryResult&);
public:
    using line_no = std::vector<std::string>::size_type;
    QueryResult(std::string s, std::shared_ptr<std::set<line_no>> p, std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> f) :sought(s), lines(p), file(f) {}
    std::set<line_no>::iterator begin(std::string) const { return lines->begin(); };
    std::set<line_no>::iterator end(std::string) const { return lines->end(); };
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> get_file() const { return std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>(file); };
private:
    std::string sought;
    std::shared_ptr < std::set<line_no>> lines;
    std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> file;
};
```

compile error：

> error C2665:
> std::vectorstd::string,std::allocator<std::string>::vector: no
> overloaded function could convert all the argument types.

Comment: In `get_file`, `file` is already a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>`.  You just need `return file;`.

Comment: Ok..this code is an example of `std::shared_ptr as antipattern`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As you can see in the [`std::make_shared` documentation](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/memory/shared_ptr/make_shared), in order to create a `std::shared_ptr<T>`, you need to pass the arguments for `T`'s constructor.

However in this line:

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> get_file() const 
             { return std::make_shared<std::vector<std::string>>(file); };
```

You pass `file` which is **not** a proper argument for constructing a `std::vector<std::string>` (your `T`).

But since `file` is already a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>`, you can simply return it instead (no need for `make_shared`):

```
std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>> get_file() const 
             { return file; }
```

Answer (score 0):

By calling `std::make_shared()`, you're calling the constructor of `std::vector<std::string>` with a `std::shared_ptr<std::vector<std::string>>` as input. That's not how `std::vector` is created (see the constructor of `std::vector<T>`).

As @NathanOliver said in [a comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/75883615/#comment133849283_75883615), just returning the member `file` as-is will be enough.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Thanks for editing my answer. As you see I'm a newbie here, and I'm wondering how can I get the link for comment. Would you kindly give me any links I can find information or some explain?

Comment: The timestamp of the comment "hides" a URL for the comment - you can e.g. open it in a new tab to get the URL.

Comment: @wohlstad Wow, I had completely no idea. Thanks a lot!

Comment: @wohlstad since the timestamp is a hyperlink, you can right-click/long-click on it to get popup options, which in most browsers includes copying the url.